# Is there any way to make Style apply to all items without having to declare property

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have created a custom style for DataGrid. There are several datagrids in my application, and I would like for this style to apply to all of them.

One way of doing this is to add `Style="{StaticResource DataGridDefaultStyle}"` to all DataGrids.

But there must be an other way of doing this, similar to adding a theme, where I would declare style, and it would automatically apply to all DataGrids.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the implicit style as other have stated, but put it in your App.Xaml file's Application.Resources section, this will allow the style to be applied to all DataGrids in your application.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

check this [Using CSS Selectors for Styling in WPF](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/03/using-css-selectors-for-styling-in-wpf/)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using an [implicit style](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/implicit-style/).

Answer (score 1):

To create an implicit style, you must not include a key for the style and specify the TargetType. If you do so, the style will automatically be applied to each style of the specified type.

For example, this code will be automatically applied to all DataGrid elements:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
     <!-- style information goes here -->
</Style>
```